# Realtime picture fetching from Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have been having a slight problem with Amazon S3.

I have made a fully-functioning backend where I can upload and download files on a mobile app that I created using java. It is kind of like DropBox at the moment.

I am having issues moving to the next step which is being able to see my profile picture that I have uploaded. As of now, the bucket items appear as names only. How would I go about creating something that shows a user uploaded picture upon login? The picture will vary based on the user that logged in. Currently I am using Cognito, S3 and IAM roles.

Comment: Please include your code in the question and some images referring to the problem that you encountered.

Comment: My question doesnt really require code or pics. Its more of a methods problem. I basically dont know how to bridge the gap between uploading to s3, then to finally be able to show user based pics deoending on who logged in.

Comment: `Its more of methods problem`. People can't help you properly if you don't help others to understand your problem. Thus people will have a hard time to explain to you how to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a product like Filestack to manage profile pic uploads and retrieval?